# moviepy CompositeVideoClip fails with ColorClip

Tags: python, transparency, moviepy

I want to add a semi-transparent box over a video. Following is the code I have and the error:

```
videoclip = VideoFileClip("a.mp4")
bgclip = ColorClip(size =(50, 50), color =0.5, ismask=True)
finalclip = CompositeVideoClip([videoclip,  bgclip.set_pos("center")]).set_duration(1)
finalclip.write_videofile("out.mp4")
```

But I am facing following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1920,1080,3) (1920,1080)
```

It works if bgclip is set to

```
bgclip = ColorClip(size =(50, 50), color =[100, 255, 100])
```

Error is there when mask or alpha transparent value is given. Is there  something I am missing? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bgclip = ColorClip(size =(50, 50), color =[100, 255, 100, 128])
```

This adds transparency :)
resolved